# IOS7 UIActionsheet strange borders

Tags: border, ios7, uiactionsheet, appearance

in IOS6 I had an UIActionsheet where I put a picker inside as subview. That worked find. But now in IOS7 there is a strange border around the Actionsheet. I made the backgroundcolor black to make the borders more visible. How can I get rid of them?

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't customize UIActionSheet in any way no more on iOS 7. According to [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> UIActionSheet is not designed to be subclassed, nor should you add
>   views to its hierarchy. If you need to present a sheet with more
>   customization than provided by the UIActionSheet API, you can create
>   your own and present it modally with
>   presentViewController:animated:completion:.